# Making multiple async call in a row from anonymous async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

```
   const loadJSON = () => Promise(
      async () => {
         const req = await fetch(`data.json`);
         return req.json();
      }
   );

   const loadData = (city) => Promise.all(
      city.map(async (f) => {
         const req = await fetch(`${f}/geo.json`);
         return req.json();
      })
   );

   (async () => {

      const loadedJSON = await loadJSON();
      console.log(loadedJSON);
      const loadedData = loadedJSON.map(f => f.loc);
      console.log(loadedData);

   })();
```

`data.json` just contain an array of cities (like London, Barcelona etc). With the second function I want to get the cities locations (cities location are at the `city_name/geo.json` file)

If I only use the `loadJSON` and the appropriate parts of the `anonymous async function`, I am getting the following error message:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: undefined is not a promise
    at Promise (<anonymous>)
    at loadJSON
```

What is the problem with my code?

Comment: `Promise()` should be `new Promise()`.

Comment: Why are you wrapping an async function in `Promise()`? Declaring a function `async` makes it return a promise automatically.

Comment: Also seems like a typo here console.log(loaded);

Comment: @Barmar now there is no error, but there is no console.log as well, If I am using `console.log("JSON: ", loadedJSON)` somethin appears on the screen but it suddenly disappears

Comment: That wasn't meant as the whole solution, it's just an obvious error in the code.

Comment: "const loadJSON = fetch('data.json').then(res => res.json());"